# Tell-A-Friend kind of form in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to build an in-game Tell A Friend form like in AppStore. Does anybody know if it can be found anywhere in the SDK? I wouldn't like to reinvent the sliced bread.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Short of writing your own SMTP client, you can create a message then exit your app by sending a URL to the mail app with openURL.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"mailto:gilm@myopenid.com?subject=subject&body=body"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

The user then checks the content and sends the message.

Comment: My answer has now been superseded by changes to the iPhone SDK. Refer to the MFMailComposeViewController class.

Comment: +1 (to your answer and comment) for noting your original answer's deprecation.

Answer (score 3):

In your .h file import MessageUI and MFMailComposerViewController:
`#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>`
`#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>`
You need to make your viewController MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate by adding: `<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>` like the following:

```
@interface tellAFriend : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> {
```

Also make a IBAction for telling a friend:
`-(IBAction)tellAFriend;`
**UPDATE**
For SMS, also add:
`-(IBAction)tellAFriendViaSMS;`

---

Then go into your .m and add the following code:

```
-(IBAction)tellAFriend {

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailView setSubject:@"Check Out your_app_name_here"];
[mailView setMessageBody:@"Check out your_app_name_here <br> It's really cool and I think you would like it." isHTML:YES];

[self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
[mailView release];

}

else {

NSLog(@”Mail Not Supported”);

}

}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult MFMailComposeResult)result error  NSError*)error {

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

---

**UPDATE**
You can also send SMS' using this code:

```
-(IBAction)tellAFriendViaSMS {
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    controller.body = @"Check Out your_app_name_here, itunes_link_here";
    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"phoneNumbersHere", @"PhoneNumberTwo", nil]; // Optional
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In meantime, there are some new API's in the iPhone SDK including the MessageKit.framework. That framework makes it possible to add a MFMailComposeViewController.

Hope that works,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like this in the SDK, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

As Ben says, no, there's nothing like that in the SDK. My guess is there never will. I imagine that this functionality is implemented on the server side, which is probably the best option anyway.